# Why I can't make a transition for images in css?

Tags: html, css, image

So I have a div which contains some logos. When i hover over them they should become colored instead of grey and pop up, but for some reason the transition doesn't work.

Here's the code of the div in html:

```
<div class="clients">
      <img src="img/myob.png">
     <img src="img/belimo.png">
      <img src="img/LifeGroups.png">
      <img src="img/Lilly.png">
      <img src="img/Trustly.png">
      <img src="img/Citrus.png">
    </div>
```

Code of css:

```
.clients{
  width:100%;
  height:120px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  align-items: right;
  justify-content: center;
}

.clients img{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  object-fit: contain;
  filter: grayscale(100);
}
```

So I used transition for images to pop up and become colored, but when I hover over there's no reaction.

A picture of div:

[image]

How it should be:
[image]

Comment: Where is your :hover selector in the CSS?

Comment: yes, I didn't add hover cause i didn't know how "filter" works, i feel stupid but at least now i know how it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transition works on images. Check the below snippet.

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  filter: grayscale(100);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<span>
  <img src="https://assets.dragoart.com/images/11939_501/how-to-draw-iron-man-easy_5e4c9ed9b16b58.14188289_53732_3_3.png" />
</span>
```

Comment: i actually didn't add hover, i didn't work with "filter" before so i didn't know it was necessary
thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You do not seem to have a :hover statement, try adding this:

```
.clients img:hover{
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```